# Thread stucks in the infinite loop when executed

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I have developed a chat server program using threads. In this program there are two threads:

1. One to receive data
2. One to send data

Both of the threads contain the infinite loop in order to continuously send and receive data. But when it is executed the thread for receiving data gets stuck in the loop.

The code of the server:

```
      {
            addr_len=sizeof(cli_addr);
            cli_sock=accept(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr,&addr_len);
            if(cli_sock<0)
                    printf("\nConnetion Error\n");
            else
                    printf("conneted\n");

            status_s=pthread_create(&thread_s,NULL,send_data,&cli_sock);
            if(status_s==0)
                    printf("sending");
            status_r=pthread_create(&thread_r,NULL,recieve_data,&cli_sock);
            if(status_r==0)
                    printf("recieving");

    }

    }

    void *recieve_data(void *num)
    {
    int *sock_r=(int *) num;
    int sock=*sock_r;
    char msg[50];
    while(1)
    {
            recv(sock_r,msg,sizeof(msg),0);

            if(strcmp(msg,"exit")==0)
            {
            break;
            }
            printf("recieved data:");
            recv(sock_r,msg,sizeof(msg),0);
            printf("\n%s",msg);
    }
    }

    void *send_data(void *num)
    {
    int *sock_s=(int *) num;
    int sock=*sock_s;
    char msg[50];
    while(1)
    {
            gets(msg);
            //printf("sending data");
            if(strcmp(msg,"exit")==0)
            {
            break;
            }
            send(sock_s,msg,sizeof(msg),0);
    }
    send(sock,msg,sizeof(msg),0);

    }
```

Comment: Do you know about and use the `poll(2)` syscall? Did you read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ or other Unix programming book?

Comment: What do you get if you print "msg" ?

Comment: You should check the return value of recv.

Answer (score 0):

Would be better if control commands like "exit" are int based.

Also, receive data doesn't handle peer connection closure status. Ex:
Copied from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
// Receive until the peer closes the connection
do {

    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if ( iResult > 0 )
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
    else if ( iResult == 0 )
        printf("Connection closed\n");
    else
        printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

} while( iResult > 0 );
```

Comment: Keep in mind that printf and similar library functions aren't necessarily thread-safe.